# Will a death route be locked if I die without getting any checkpoints?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

Some levels in Crash 2 & 3 have "death routes" that can only be accessed if you reach them without dying. Obviously the route would be locked if I die and respawn at a checkpoint, but would the death route be locked if I die before hitting any checkpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, death routes will not be locked if you die without activating any checkpoints.

I tested this in the Crash 2 stage Air Crash. Despite dying multiple times, the death route was still available as I had not activated any checkpoints. It was even still available after I died during the death route and had to restart the level.